# Back button logs user out of app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on a sign up/login flow using Firebase. Both activities after successful authentication open Main activity using an intent and finish();. The problem I am having is in main activity, if I press back once it closes the app and when I open app it goes back to main activity. But after I do this second time , press back, when I open the app it goes back to either the login or sign up activity. Which ever was used to access it. I thought it maybe could be something to do with the activity life cycle. I also tried to use a listener to maybe keep main activity running when app is opened. On apps like Facebook, you can open app press back to exit and open it again as many times as you want and it does not log you out or anything

I was able to solve the login activity problem with `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(LoginActivity.this);` after intent. Now when I click back 2 times and exit app, when I open app it takes me to sign up activity. ie. FIRST TIME LAUNCH `Sign up activity --> LoginActivity -->  Mainacitivty -- back button(exit app), open app -- MainActivity-- back button(exit app)-- open app, back button --> SignUpActivity` Here is where I think the problem is, android manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When I exit the app from back button and open it again, the app is launching the SignUpActivity. So now I have to figure out a way to check if user is still signed in and redirect to MainActivity. This is what I have read and tried.

```
       // get girebase auth instance

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Check to see if user is signed in
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null){
                //user is signed in
                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                Log.d("", "onAuthStateChanged: Signed_in: " + user.getUid());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User status : " + user.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //
        }
    };
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have been dealing with this problem for 4 days now

Comment: Post the relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

After a sign in or a sign up has been successfully done, finish the activity when launching the new activity using the code:

```
finish()
```

Hope this works.